# FFmpeg input duration?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

With FFmpeg you have the option `-t` which will set the duration of the output. However I do not see a way to limit the duration of the **input**. Take this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -t 60 out.mp4
```

This simply creates a 60 second clip of the original video. However if I wanted to clip the **audio** while keeping the full video stream, FFmpeg does not seem to have an option for this.

I have tried simply clipping the audio first, then combining the clipped audio with the video file, but this causes video/audio sync issues for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
‘-aframes number (output)’

    Set the number of audio frames to record. This is an alias for -frames:a.
```

[§ Audio Options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -aframes 100 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "-itsoffset" option.
This makes the first 10 seconds mute.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy -ss 10.0 out_audio.mp4
ffmpeg -itsoffset 10.0 -i out_audio.mp4 -i video.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

Comment: If you simply want to ignore audio there is -an. If you want to control how many frames of input to use -vframes is an option. If you want to use say 100 frames of input from 23rd second -ss 23.0 -vframes 100 will do that for you. Combine with -an and you will have no audio at all.